# Global variables not recognized in lambda functions in Pyspark

Tags: python, lambda, pyspark, global, nonetype

I am working in Pyspark with a lambda function like the following:

```
udf_func = UserDefinedFunction(lambda value: method1(value, dict_global), IntegerType())
result_col = udf_func(df[atr1])
```

The implementation of the method1 is the next one:

```
def method1(value, dict_global):
    result = len(dict_global)
    if (value in dict_global):
        result = dict_global[value]
    return result
```

'dict_global' is a global dictionary that contains some values.

The problem is that when I execute the lambda function the result is always None. For any reason the 'method1' function doesn't interpret the variable 'dict_global' as an external variable. Why? What could I do?

Comment: Well, `method1` is interpreting `dict_global` as a function argument.  The question is, where is the `lambda` function looking for `dict_global`?  As long as it isn't being masked by some local definition, then the `lambda` function should be looking for it in the global context in which the `lambda` was defined.

Comment: I pass the dictionary as a parameter because when I tried the same without passing the dict as a parameter I get the same result... 'None'

Comment: If you pass it as an argument, you should rewrite it
`udf_func = lambda dict_global: UserDefinedFunction(lambda value: method1(value, dict_global), IntegerType())`
`result_col = udf_func(dict_global)(df[atr1])`

Comment: Can you write it as an answer please? I get syntax error when trying to apply your suggestion...

Comment: I continue with the same problem, even if I apply your suggestion Marie...

Answer (score 16):

Finally I found a solution. I write it below:

Lambda functions (as well as map and reduce functions) executed in SPARK schedule the executions among the different executors, and it works in different execution threads. So the problem in my code could be global variables sometimes are not caught by the functions executed in parallel in different threads, so I looked for a solution to try solve it.

Fortunately, in SPARK there is an element called ["Broadcast"](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/programming-guide.html#shared-variables) which allows to pass variables to the execution of a function organized among the executors to work with them without problems. There are 2 type of sharable variables: Broadcast (inmutable variables, only for read) and accumulators (mutable variables, but numeric values only accepted).

I rewrite my code to show you how did I fix the problem:

```
broadcastVar = sc.broadcast(dict_global)
udf_func = UserDefinedFunction(lambda value: method1(value, boradcastVar), IntegerType())
result_col = udf_func(df[atr1])
```

Hope it helps!